# CQ5 response.sendRedirect with dispatcher

Tags: aem, sling

I would like to redirect a request to an other page by some condition. In cq5 I can check whether the page I want to redirect the request exists or not. But dispatcher handles only static HTML, so how I can handle redirects to be compatible with dispatcher?

So how can I use response.sendRedirect() with dispatcher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a page that sometimes redirects to somewhere else and sometimes simply displays a content. If the page decides to redirect, dispatcher won't cache it. However, if the page displays a content (even once), it will be cached and from this moment all users will get the cached resource.

You can do 2 things:

- move the redirection logic to Javascript, so it'll executed even if the page is cached,
- add a cache rule to dispatcher configuration preventing this concrete path from being cached.